# Windows.Media.Ocr.OcrEngine is not registered

Tags: windows, powershell, ocr

On PS documentation, it is said to use `[Windows.Media.Ocr.OcrEngine, Windows.Foundation, ContentType = WindowsRuntime]` then `[Windows.Media.Ocr.OcrEngine]::AvailableRecognizerLanguages` to get OCR language packs, however for me when ever I type in the second command I get

```
    Le type Windows Runtime demandé 'Windows.Media.Ocr.OcrEngine' n'est pas enregistré.
    Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
    + [Windows.Media.Ocr.OcrEngine]::AvailableRecognizerLanguages
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], TypeLoadException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.TypeLoadException
```

Sorry it's in french but it means the engine is not registered. My powertoy text extractor crash instantly when I try to use it and I feel like this is related to the error I get when ever I try to use the command above. I have language packs installed (they're present in C / OCR) and show up as installed if I run `DISM /Online /Get-Capabilities` and look for Language.OCR)

Comment: What version of the operating system are you using?

Comment: W11 build 22621

Comment: Is the system installed on drive C? PowerToys had problems with this.

Comment: as i said in my question it is on the drive C.

Comment: could you show the result of the command `Get-WindowsCapability -Online | Where-Object { $_.Name -Like 'Language.OCR*' }` ?

Comment: This returns the same as DISM Get-Capabilities, and returns 2 Language.OCR pack: en-US and fr-FR as installed